# How to add font awesome to ASP.NET Core Angular 2 application in Visual Studio 2017 with SpaTemplates

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, font-awesome, visual-studio-2017

I am using the Single Page Application Template in Visual Studio 2017 in order to create an Angular 2 application.

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

And then created the application like this:

```
dotnet new angular
```

What is the reccommended way of importing third Party libraries like font awesome into the Angular 2 application?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/dev/templates/AngularSpa/webpack.config.vendor.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455594/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-a-net-core-2-spa-with-angular-4-project)

This is for .NET Core 2, after you create a SPA Project using dotnet new angular:

1. Go to the root of the project and install the package: npm install font-awesome --save. You should now see it in package.json dependencies.
2. After that go to webpack.config.vendor.js and add font awesome to the array under non tree shakable modules:

   const nonTreeShakableModules = [
       'bootstrap',
       'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
       'es6-promise',
       'es6-shim',
       'event-source-polyfill',
       'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
       'jquery',
   ];
3. Now we need to tell the webpack that we added this new package. So if you haven't done so before install this in the root of project with npm install --save-dev npm-install-webpack-plugin.
4. Finally, run this command in the root of project: webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the exact same thing.

Finally found the answer here: 
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

Don't forget to do:

`webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`

as mentioned and also make sure you also restart the ASP.NET Core pipeline upon doing so.

Regards

Comment: everytime I run webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js I get TypeError: dep.getResourceIdentifier is not a function any thoughts?