# How to add font awesome to a .net core 2 spa with angular 4 project

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, asp.net-core-2.0

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796541/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-angular-2-cli-project?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I don't have an angular cli file so I tried to install with `npm` and then add it with `import` statement in my `wwwroot/css/style.css` file but that didn't work either.

EDIT: My project is an Angular 4 App With Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web API so the suggested tutorial was unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: You can add this to your index.html : `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: Sure but isn't it better to add it as a package?

Comment: How would it be better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add font awesome to ASP.NET Core Angular 2 application in Visual Studio 2017 with SpaTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071115/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-asp-net-core-angular-2-application-in-visual-studio-2)

Comment: I already followed that article still couldn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[How to add font awesome to ASP.NET Core Angular 2 application in Visual Studio 2017 with SpaTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071115/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-asp-net-core-angular-2-application-in-visual-studio-2) I reread the article and found that I missed something. I resolved the issue.