# Where to add global css in an Angular 2 application made with Visual Studio 2017 Angular template

Tags: css, angular, visual-studio, webpack, asp.net-core

I'm new in Angular and I have created an Angular 2 application using Visual Studio 2017 Angular Spa template.

I want to add Angular Material to my project and in its guide said that I have to add this:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">`

But I don't know where.

I have add it inside `app.component.css` file:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500");
```

But I get a warning:

> (CssLint) @import prevents parallel downloads, use  instead.

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47629418/68571), but I don't think it applies to my problem.

Where can I add styles or fonts to use them globally?

Answer (score 1):

In your Angular project folder you should got to `src/app/`. In the `app`-folder you can see `index.html` and `styles.css`. So this two files are global. You can add font styles in `index.html` od via `@import` in `styles.css`.

In case of your question you should have an `index.html` in your `wwwroot` folder. In [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/setting-up-angular-project-with-asp-net-core-and-visual-studio-2017/) the author does so.

For example `index.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ....
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, this is an Angular made with Visual Studio 2017 SPA Template. There is no src folder, or `src/app` folder or `index.html` file.

Comment: @VansFannel I updated my answer. Check wwwroot-folder for index.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to Angular, I can only advise you to follow their guidelines.

And one of their guidelines is to create a project [using the Angular CLI](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).

Once you've created the project, if you want to add Angular Material, follow their guide too.

About your font issue : you're not trying to import a style, you're trying to import a font. Fonts goes in the index.html page, in the head. @Gregor placed it well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer that you posted actually applies to you, but firstly you should download this font and copy it to your project dir so it can be static asset. Then you can import this file using `webpack plugin` ([look here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/)). I'm not familiar with project generated by Visual Studio you can just simply add your `link` tag to `index.html` inside `head` tag.

```
<html>
<head>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
...
</html>
```

Comment: This is an Angular made with Visual Studio 2017 SPA Template and there is no `index.html` file. There is a `Views\Home\Index.cshtml`.

Comment: Finally, I have moved it to `View\Shared\_Layout.cshtml`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can anyway add `link` tag to index.cshtml, since it also process staticaly defined tags html.

Answer (score 0):

Only add our CSS files to the nonTreeShakableModules array of the webpack.config.vendor.js, e.g. my webpack.config.vendor is like

```
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.css',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill'
];
```

That's because of you have (in the same webpack.config.vendor)

```
const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
    }
```

In case of a font I don't know if the best solucion it's simply add a link in _layout.cshtml as @Gregorg say