# webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js results in TypeError: dep.getResourceIdentifiier is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

in visual studio 2017 and visual studio 2017 preview I am creating a new ASP.Net Core 2.1 Angular application from the templates.   unfortunately every time I try and run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js` I receive

```
 TypeError: dep.getResourceIdentifier is not a function
    at addDependency (C:\Users\bdellinger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:387:30)
    at iterationOfArrayCallback (C:\Users\bdellinger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:78:3)
    at addDependenciesBlock (C:\Users\bdellinger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:407:5)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (C:\Users\bdellinger\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:418:4) ...
```

here is my package.json (I've tried many different versions of webpack from 2 to 4 but always get the same thing)

```
{
  "name": "AngularSPABootstrap4",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.9.5",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "tabable": "^1.0.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-link": "^0.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  }
}
```

this is related to this question [How to add font awesome to ASP.NET Core Angular 2 application in Visual Studio 2017 with SpaTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071115/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-asp-net-core-angular-2-application-in-visual-studio-2) where I am attempting to add font awesome to the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run webpack at all if you are using the new ASP.NET Core 2.1 template since it is based on the Angular cli which handles this things behind the scenes.
To use font awesome just install the angular component they provide. Here is the link from the official site. [Font Awesome Angular Component](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular)

If you don't want to use the component you can also import in in the styles.css like this:

```
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css');
```

Then you can use it like in plain HTML like this:

```
<i class="fas fa-stroopwafel"></i>
```

This is described [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use).

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest template? Because you should not have webpack.config files at all in your angular application if you created it with the ASP.NET Core 2.1 template. This was like that in the old ASP.NET core 1.1 template.

Comment: thanks tried that I am now getting.....Refused to load the image
  because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
  "default-src 'self'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so
  'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: I cannot say anything about that without seeing what you are doing. This looks like it is a browser security issue. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447970/content-security-policy-data-not-working-for-base64-images-in-chrome-28) if it will help.